# Why do you need to name a datatable before binding it to a dataview?

Tags: vb.net, data-binding, dataview

When I bind a Dataview I can just dump a DataTable into it without any problems

```
Dim dtTable As New DataTable
Dim dvTable As New DataView
dvTable.Table = dtTable
```

This works just fine.

However in my new project I get the error "Cannot bind to DataTable with no name." when trying to bind a table;

```
Public Class frmInvoiceCategories
Dim intDtInvoiceRowCount As Integer = 0
Dim dtItemCategory1() As DataTable
Dim dtItemCategory2() As DataTable
Dim dvItemCategory2 As New DataView
Dim blnDtCategory2Functional As Boolean = False

Private Sub frmInvoiceCategories_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ReDim cboInvoiceItemTypeMajor(intDtInvoiceRowCount) 'resize the array to fit enough
    ReDim cboInvoiceItemTypeMinor(intDtInvoiceRowCount) 'resize the array to fit enough
    ReDim dtItemCategory2(intDtInvoiceRowCount) 'resize the array to fit enough dt
    subLoadCboItemCategory2() 'load all the item categories for the subcategory cbo    
End Sub

Private Sub subLoadCboItemCategory2()
        Dim dtItemCategory2Main As New DataTable 'create a temporary dt to check if all the columns are in this dt, then copy the dt
        dtItemCategory2Main = fnGetItemCategory2(0) 'get all item subcategories

        'check if the dt is functional
        If dtItemCategory2Main IsNot Nothing Then 'does the dt exist?
            If dtItemCategory2Main.Columns.Count > 0 Then 'does the dt have columns?
                If dtItemCategory2Main.Columns.Contains("ID") Then 'does it have an ID column?
                    If dtItemCategory2Main.Columns.Contains("Category2") Then 'does it have a dislpayname column?
                        blnDtCategory2Functional = True 'table is complete enough to run
                    Else
                        MsgBox("Data table category2 doesn't have category2 column")
                    End If
                Else
                    MsgBox("Data table category2 doesn't have ID column")
                End If
            Else
                MsgBox("Data table category2 doesn't have columns")
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox("Data table category2 is nothing")
        End If

        If blnDtCategory2Functional = True Then 'if the dt is complete
            For intIndex = 0 To intDtInvoiceRowCount Step 1 'count through all the rows in the dt
                dtItemCategory2(intIndex) = New DataTable 'create a new instance of the dt
                dtItemCategory2(intIndex) = dtItemCategory2Main 'copy the main dt
            Next
        Else 'the dt is incomplete
            MsgBox("form is unusable, closing down")
            Me.Close()
        End If
    End Sub

Private Sub cboInvoiceItemTypeMajor_SelectionChangeCommitted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
dvItemCategory2.Table = dtItemCategory2(intIndex)
End Sub
End Class
```

Why do I suddenly have to name the table? The reference to the table object within the array is there.
Can it be done without giving it a name?

Comment: Are you aware that every `DataTable` is automatically associated with a `DataView`, accessible via its `DefaultView` property? In fact, when you bind a `DataTable` in a WinForms app, the data you see in the UI actually comes from that `DataView`, which is how you are able to sort the data when bound to a `DataGridView`. The only reason you would need to explicitly create a `DataView` is that you need multiple views of the same table.

Comment: Not at all aware of that. Also a little confused as to how this is relevant to having to name every table before being able to bind it to a dataview. The link to the object is right there; 'dvItemCategory2.Table = dtItemCategory2(intIndex)' this should say enough as to which object i'm binding to the Dataview, right? Also, creating a dataview has more uses than needing multiple view of the same table; such as filtering and sorting properly, as tables can't do this, or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes you are missing something. You're missing how my comment is relevant. It's relevant because they're is no problem to solve if you don't create a DataView in the first place and you don't have to create a DataView because one already exists. Just use the DefaultView of the DataTable and your question becomes moot.

Comment: Also, on the rare occasions that you actually do need to create a DataView, just use the constructor that takes a DataTable as an argument. I could be wrong but I'm fairly sure I've done that with an unnamed DataTable before without issue.

Comment: If every datatable comes with its own dataview, why I can't filter the records in the datatable? `dtItemCategory2(intIndex).rowfilter = "Category_ID=" & intCategory1_ID` gives the error "rowfilter is not a member of datatable" that doesn't happen when I use a dataview. If you have the patience, I'm still interested in understanding WHY I need to set a name for every table, seems a little redundant to me as there is only 1 object with that reference (dtItemCategory2(intIndex)), whats the point of naming it? why doesn't that sets its name to dtItemCategory2(intIndex)?

Comment: How many times do I have to post the same thing? You use the `DefaultView` property of the `DataTable` to access that `DataView`. No `RowFilter` property is magically going to appear on the `DataTable`. You still have to use a `DataView`. My point is that you don't have to create one because one already exists. You still have to get the one that already exists though.

Answer (score 0):

As I keep saying, a `DataTable` already has a `DataView` associated with it so just use that. As far as I can tell from that somewhat dodgy code, you should be able to just change this:

```vb
Dim dvItemCategory2 As New DataView
```

to this:

```vb
Dim dvItemCategory2 As DataView
```

and this:

```vb
dvItemCategory2.Table = dtItemCategory2(intIndex)
```

to this:

```vb
dvItemCategory2 = dtItemCategory2(intIndex).DefaultView
```

EDIT:

With regards to the specific issue that the question refers to, I don't know how you were ever able to do this because I just looked at the source code for that `DataView.Table` property and it looks like this:

```cs
[RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.All)]
[ResDescription("DataViewTableDescr")]
[DefaultValue(null)]
[TypeConverter(typeof (DataTableTypeConverter))]
[ResCategory("DataCategory_Data")]
public DataTable Table
{
  get => this.table;
  set
  {
    Bid.Trace("<ds.DataView.set_Table|API> %d#, %d\n", this.ObjectID, value != null ? value.ObjectID : 0);
    if (this.fInitInProgress && value != null)
    {
      this.delayedTable = value;
    }
    else
    {
      if (this.locked)
        throw ExceptionBuilder.SetTable();
      if (this.dataViewManager != null)
        throw ExceptionBuilder.CanNotSetTable();
      if (value != null && value.TableName.Length == 0)
        throw ExceptionBuilder.CanNotBindTable();
      if (this.table == value)
        return;
      this.dvListener.UnregisterMetaDataEvents();
      this.table = value;
      if (this.table != null)
        this.dvListener.RegisterMetaDataEvents(this.table);
      this.SetIndex2("", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows, (IFilter) null, false);
      if (this.table != null)
        this.OnListChanged(new ListChangedEventArgs(ListChangedType.PropertyDescriptorChanged, (PropertyDescriptor) new DataTablePropertyDescriptor(this.table)));
      this.OnListChanged(DataView.ResetEventArgs);
    }
  }
}
```

The relevant part for this discussion is this:

```cs
if (value != null && value.TableName.Length == 0)
  throw ExceptionBuilder.CanNotBindTable();
```

I'm not sure why it should be a problem to use a `DataTable` with no name - the constructor that takes a `DataTable` as an argument has no such restriction - but it's pretty clear that you can't.